# Get the group index in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), b = c('A','A','A','B','B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'), c = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))
> DT
     a b c
 1:  1 A 1
 2:  2 A 1
 3:  3 A 1
 4:  4 B 1
 5:  5 B 1
 6:  6 C 2
 7:  7 C 2
 8:  8 C 2
 9:  9 D 2
10: 10 D 2
```

I want to add a column that shows the index grouped by c (starts from 1 from each group in column c), but that only changes when the value of b is changed. The result wanted is shown below:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do this :

1. Using `rleid` :

```
library(data.table)
DT[, col := rleid(b), c]
```

2. With `match` + `unique` :

```
DT[, col := match(b, unique(b)), c]

#     a b c col
# 1:  1 A 1   1
# 2:  2 A 1   1
# 3:  3 A 1   1
3 4:  4 B 1   2
# 5:  5 B 1   2
# 6:  6 C 2   1
# 7:  7 C 2   1
# 8:  8 C 2   1
# 9:  9 D 2   2
#10: 10 D 2   2
```

Comment: Thank you. Was trying with rleid and .GRP without any success.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `factor` with `levels` specified and coerce it to `integer`

```
library(data.table)
DT[, col := as.integer(factor(b, levels = unique(b))), c]
```

-output

```
DT
#      a b c col
# 1:  1 A 1   1
# 2:  2 A 1   1
# 3:  3 A 1   1
# 4:  4 B 1   2
# 5:  5 B 1   2
# 6:  6 C 2   1
# 7:  7 C 2   1
# 8:  8 C 2   1
# 9:  9 D 2   2
#10: 10 D 2   2
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rle`

```
with(DT, as.integer(ave(b, c, FUN = function(x) 
       with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))))
```